# How do I specifiy an object directory in a Qt project file?

Tags: qt, configuration, build-process, qmake

I am building a console Qt project.

Currently, my project file looks like this:

```
CONFIG += qt console debug 
CONFIG -= app_bundle

HEADERS = HelperClass.h
SOURCES = HelperClass.cpp \
            main.cpp
TARGET = doit
```

My QMAKESPEC environment variable is set to: `macx-g++`

I go to the directory with the project (and source) files and run `qmake` (which builds a Makefile) then `make` to build the project.  The object files (*.o) from the compilation are placed in the same directory with my source and the executable.

How do I configure this build to place those object files in a sub directory so they don't pollute my source area?

Comment: Are you satisfied with the .o file being in a subdir?  What about moc files, resource files, generated makefiles, etc.?  So far I am setting OBJECTS_DIR, MOC_DIR, DESTDIR, RCC_DIR, UI_DIR, UI_HEADERS_DIR, and UI_SOURCES_DIR, and everything goes into my 'obj' directory, except the generated makefiles.  I thought I'd be home free with QMAKE_MAKEFILE, but that doesn't seem to like a path as part of the name (and it gets ignored by QtCreator, anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set OBJECTS_DIR:

```
OBJECTS_DIR = ../myproject/tmp
```

See http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qmake-variable-reference.html#objects-dir